# Angular mat-form-field center alignment

Tags: angular, angular-material

Everywhere you can find how to center the text and even placeholder and labels and everything but I can't center the whole form-field and it looks ugly as hell.

```
<div class="mat-app-background basic-container">
  <div layout-gt-sm="column" style="min-width: 350px; max-width: 450px; margin:auto">
    <mat-card flex-gt-sm class="push">
      <div style="text-align:center;">
        <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
      <mat-card-content>
        <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form" (ngSubmit)="login()">
          <table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field>
                    <div style="text-align:center;">
                  <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN.USERNAME' | translate }}" name="username"
                    formControlName="username" type="name" />
                  <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.username" class="form__error">{{ formErrors.username }} </mat-error>
                </div>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

I hope this code needs. If not I will post the rest of the html. But it's just about centering the fields. Didn't used CSS here.

[image]

Comment: You could wrap it like `<div class="flexbox-parent">
  <div layout="row" layout-align="center center">Username & Password fields</div></div>`

Comment: See if that works - if not, I can help you if you post up a snippet of code to a fiddle or stackblitz.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend you to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

I am also not sure why do you need to put it inside a , but I have removed it to simplify the demo.

```
<div class="parent">
  <mat-form-field>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
      <input matInput placeholder="{{ 'LOGIN.USERNAME' | translate }}" name="username" formControlName="username" type="name" />
      <mat-error *ngIf="formErrors.username" class="form__error">{{ formErrors.username }} </mat-error>
    </div>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

And on your CSS,

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

The properties `justify-content` and `align-items` with the value of `center` will center the flex children along the line and in the cross-axis respectively, thus placing them on the centre of the page. The property `flex-direction` with the value of `column` aligns the children (form fields) from top to bottom.

Comment: You are not sure why I need to put it inside what? It simply doesn't work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant putting inside a table*

Comment: Sorry I wasn't working the last days. It's not working for me. @wentjun simply nothing happens.

Comment: Just when I do style="display..." for the div in the html then it does work. But the CSS does not get applied. Already deleted table and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can put `style="text-align:center;"` inside `input` element.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" [style.width.em]="8">
    <mat-label>Início</mat-label>
    <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" maxlength="10" matInput formControlName="segundaInicio">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This works for centering the placeholder and value, but not the mat-label and mat-error